# Converting Hours and Minutes to Minutes Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

Goal: calculate pay for elapsed time.

Short question is how can I convert the time value of hours and minutes to just minutes in Excel to calculate payment for hours worked? For example, I have a time value of 2:15 (two hours and fifteen minutes) that I wish to convert to the number 135. Alternatively, converting to a decimal value of hours would work. That would convert 2:15 to 2.25.

Expanded:

I have a time tracking spreadsheet that uses military time. Two of the fields are Start Time and End Time. A simple formula (=d3-c2 or =start_time-end_time) yields the time elapsed in a third field. However, the result is in hours and minutes which I can't use to calculate the pay for this period. I'd like to create a fourth field that converts the two hours and fifteen minutes value to either minutes only (135) or the decimal hours representation of two hours fifteen minutes (2.25).

I will convert the minutes only to a decimal value of the hours and multiply by the pay rate or if the decimal value can be achieved in a single step, I'll multiply pay rate by that.

Ultimately, I wish, if the pay rate is $10/hr. to have a field showing the person is owed $22.50 for the time worked. Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Note that, depending on your labour laws &/or union agreement, you may need to round up to the quarter, half, or full hour.

Answer (score 1):

Provided your source value is stored as a Date/Time, you can extract the hours and minutes directly using `HOUR()` and `MINUTE()`

Example, where cell A1 is the time value `2:15:00` (two hours, 15 minutes, no seconds). This formula will return a numeric value of 135 minutes. Format it as a number, not as a date/time:

```
=HOUR(A1)*60+MINUTE(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time is stored in Excel as a number of days with a fraction.
To convert this number to minutes all you need to do is to
multiply it by:

> 1 Day = 24 Hours = 24 * 60 or **1440 Minutes**

A simple formula will be `=A1*1440`, stored in a cell that
is defined as number with zero digits after the point.

You may also use the
[CONVERT function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/convert-function-d785bef1-808e-4aac-bdcd-666c810f9af2)
like this : `=CONVERT(A1, "day", "hr")`.

For more information with examples see the article
[How to Convert Time to Minutes in Excel](https://earnandexcel.com/blog/how-to-convert-time-to-minutes-in-excel/).